# SVG elements seem to ignore border-box sizing before reflow?

Tags: html, css, svg

When using `box-sizing: border-box;` in CSS, the border of the element is included in the total width and height. I have SVG elements set to 100% width inside a parent div also using `border-box`, and when that SVG has a border set on it, there seems to be rendering/size issues.

I've replicated the issue on this stackblitz (with div elements for comparison): https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-xytlg2

I see the issue in Chrome and Firefox. In Firefox, the SVG elements have their borders extending past the purple div. In Chrome, they do the same, but hovering the mouse over each SVG will cause the border to be recalculated and then it fits inside the parent div. Removing the `box-shadow` CSS will cause that recalc effect to go away. Also, somehow, removing `body { margin: 0px; }` causes the SVGs to be rendered correctly inside the parent div, but isn't an ideal solution (and seems totally unrelated).

What is causing the SVG elements to be wider than 100%, when the div elements with the exact same CSS are properly rendered at 100% with the border inside the parent div?

Edit:
CSS:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
body { margin: 0px; } 

#main {
    display: flex; 
    height: 100%;
}

#sidebar {
    background-color: rgba(166, 64, 255, 0.07); 
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #A640FF;
}

.slide {
    margin-top: 6px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-width: 100%;
    border: 5px solid #000000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.slide:hover {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 5px solid #3030F9;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,200,0.5);
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div id="main">
  <div id="sidebar">
    <div class="slide"  max-width="100%" max-height="100%">div stuff</div>
    <svg class="slide"
        max-width="100%" max-height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1920 1080">
    </svg>
    <svg class="slide"
        max-width="100%" max-height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1920 1080">
    </svg>
    <div class="slide"  max-width="100%" max-height="100%">div stuff</div>
    <svg class="slide"
        max-width="100%" max-height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1920 1080">
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add to your Slide: width:100%;

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: There is no max-width or max-height attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`max-height` and `max-width` aren't HTML attributes; removing them from index.html results in exactly the same behavior in Chrome, and DevTools insists that max-{height,width} are unset. Instead you should set the max-{height,width} CSS properties, either through a `style` attribute or in your style.css.

What seems to have happened is that Chrome computed the element width before `box-sizing:border-box` went into effect and your `.slide:hover{box-shadow:…}` is causing it to recompute the layout. Resizing the window also triggers this.

Comment: Yeah, my issue was trying to use max-width/max-height as HTML attributes instead of in a style tag/as CSS. Changing it fixed the issue.